# Angular 2 child component not updating when datasource changes

Tags: angular, typescript, parent-child, single-page-application, angular2-docheck

I have created a table component that generates a table based on a configuration I pass in. I'm aware there are likely better ways of writing a re-usable component, but for now this is what I have.

Basically the component takes a config with a columns and datasource object then it maps the columns to the properties in the datasource.

My problem is that at some point I make changes to one of the table's datasources, I first empty the array for instance...

```
this.members.datasource = []
```

then I push the new data onto the datasource like so...

```
for (let member in members) {
            this.members.datasource.push(members[member]);
}
```

My problem is that when I do this the table does not update with the new data in the datasource.

I have utilized the ngDoCheck function in my component and it does indeed trigger when I change the datasource, but nothing else happens.

Here is all relative code and markup...

ip-datatable component

```
import { Component, Input, Output, OnInit, EventEmitter, ElementRef, DoCheck } from "@angular/core";

import { ITable } from "./interfaces/index";

@Component({
    selector: "ip-datatable",
    templateUrl: "./ip-dataTable.component.html"
})
export class IpDataTableComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
    @Input()
    public config: ITable;
    public tableData: any;

    @Output()
    private onRowClick = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(private elem: ElementRef) {

    }

    public ngOnInit() {
        // TODO: Decide whether or not to make this more dynamic (ie: excepts functions returning things other than a promise)
        if (typeof (this.config.datasource) == "function") {
            this.config.datasource()
                .then((data: any) => {
                    this.tableData = data;
                });
        } else {
            this.tableData = this.config.datasource;
        }
    }

    public rowClicked(e:Event) {
        this.onRowClick.emit(e);
    }

    public ngDoCheck() {

    }
}
```

The ip-datatable component's template html

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let column of config.columns">{{column.header}}</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr 
        *ngFor="let item of tableData" 
        [class]="(config.rowConfig !== undefined) ? config.rowConfig.classes : ''" 
        (click)="rowClicked($event)" [id]="(item.id !== undefined) ? item.id : ''">
        <td *ngFor="let column of config.columns">{{item[column.mapKey]}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Component that utilizes ip-datatable

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ApplicationRef } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { EngagementService } from "../../services/engagement.service";

import { EngagementEditModel } from "../../models/index";
import { ITable } from "../../core/components/ip-datatable/interfaces/index";

@Component({
    templateUrl: "engagement-context.component.html"
})

export class EngagementContextComponent {
    public id: string;
    public engagementDetails: EngagementEditModel;

    // Temporarily hardcode groups as there is only two available.
    public groups: ITable = {
        columns: [
            {
                header: "Name",
                mapKey: "name"
            }
        ],
        rowConfig: {
            classes: "clickable override"
        },
        datasource: [
        {
            name: "Owners"
        },
        {
            name: "Users"
        }]
    };

    public members: ITable = {
        columns: [
            {
                header: "Name",
                mapKey: "name"
            }
        ],
        datasource: []
    }

    constructor(private engagementService: EngagementService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private appRef: ApplicationRef) {
        this.id = route.snapshot.params["id"];
            this.engagementService.getEngagementEditDetailsById(parseInt(this.id))
            .then((data: EngagementEditModel) => {
                this.engagementDetails = data;
                console.log(this.engagementDetails); // tslint:disable-line
            });
    }

    public groupClicked(e: Event) {
        // Get the element of the event
        let elem: IEventElement = e.currentTarget;
        // Get the name of the selected node
        let groupName = elem.textContent.trim().toLowerCase();
        let members = (<any>this.engagementDetails)[groupName];

        interface IEventElement extends EventTarget {
            textContent?: string;
        }

        this.members.datasource = [];

        for (let member in members) {
            this.members.datasource.push(members[member]);
        }
    }
}
```

HTML usage of the ip-datatable

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <section class="section">
                <div class="section-body">
                    <h4 class="section-title">Groups</h4>
                    <ip-datatable
                        [config]="groups"
                        (onRowClick)="groupClicked($event)">
                    </ip-datatable>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <section class="section">
                <div class="section-body">
                    <h4 class="section-title">Members</h4>
                    <ip-datatable
                        [config]="members"
                    ></ip-datatable>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Alright, so my problem was that in ngOnInit I assign this.config.datasource to a variable called tableData. Well when the change happens it never gets reassigned to that variable so by calling the ngDoCheck function and then assigning this.config.datasource to tableData I get the change reflected as I wanted.

Given that I've heard of ngDoCheck's performance hindrance I may do something else if I start noticing performance drawbacks. If someone could give some insight into this in the comments, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Could you please update your answer to the correct code?

Comment: @MarkEllul Sorry, this was so long ago I have since lost the code. If you are having problems feel free to reach out to me.

Comment: I think the best way to do it is referencing the childView and calling a refresh() function that reassigns the variables

Answer (score 1):

You can use ChangedetectionStartegy.onPush(), since this refreshes the data automatically and detect the changes whenever the datasource changes and notifies the UI same, also consider declaring your datasource as an array.